# TeamCity trigger build with many VCS roots on merge request but with merge request code coming only from one repo

Tags: gitlab, teamcity, merge-request

I'm using TeamCity 2019.2 with Gitlab and I have set up already a build which can be triggered whenever there is a merge request created.

So my build uses 4 vcs roots and I've found when there is an issue when merge request with same number exists on other roots, i.e
new merge request was created on root_1 with id 33
it turned out there is an old mr with the same id in root_4

therefor build was triggered with source code fetched from new mr/33 for root_1 and and old mr for root_4
and default branches for root_2 and root_3

which of course is incorrect

in gitlab all these 4 projects have a webhook configured to be run on push and merge events to those particular roots, so:
project_1 -> root_1
project_2 -> root_2
...

all roots sitting within one build

As a workaround I have created four individual builds which monitors MR request on dedicated root only, so:

root_1_mr_build:

- root_1 - merge-requests/*
- root_2 - default
- root_3 - default
- root_4 - default

root_2_mr_build:

- root_1 - default
- root_2 - merge-requests/*
- root_3 - default
- root_4 - default

etc

Comment: just a side note that running builds from untrusted pushlishers' merge requests (in public repository) could lead to RCE attack (attacker could inject malicious code into scripts, executed in teamcity build steps).

Comment: and by the way i could not understand the logic of branching from your question. could you please rephrase it to be more clear?